# "ldconfig" - ничего не возвращает когда выполняется при установке rpm пакета и находится внутри %post скрипта

Tags: linux, rpm, altlinux

Вот фрагмент spec файла

```
%post
[[ -f /opt/application/scripts/setup.sh ]] && /opt/application/scripts/setup.sh --install || true
```

Внутри setup.sh есть вызов команды "ldconfig".
Я для теста добавил в скрипта строки

```
        echo DEBUG
        whoami
        ldconfig -p
        ldconfig
        ldconfig -V
        echo $?
        echo DEBUG
```

Когда этот скрипт запускается при установке пакета (например "rpm -i package.rpm")
ldconfig - вообще ничего не возвращает, даже ошибок нет, просто пустота.

А если я запущу этот скрипт на целевой системе из командной строки как обычный скрипт .sh всё успешно отрабатывает.

Такое поведение не на всех rpm системах, замечено только на нескольких версиях Альт Линукс.

Что с этим можно сделать?

(вариант с sudo не подходит "sudo ldconfig -p" - не походит, некоторые системы отказываются так запускать)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать полный путь к программе `/sbin/ldconfig` а также использовать перенаправление ошибок `/sbin/ldconfig 2>&1`